# Do you need a passport to travel from Germany to the Czech Republic?

Tags: politics, europe

Per the [McClatchy Report](http://www.mcclatchydc.com/news/politics-government/white-house/article208870264.html), [Michael Cohen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Cohen_(lawyer)) entered the Czech Republic through Germany and thereby bypassed getting a stamp on his passport from Czech officials.  This is pertinent as he used the lack of a stamp as evidence that he had not met with Russian officials on that trip.

> But investigators have traced evidence that Cohen entered the Czech Republic through Germany, apparently during August or early September of 2016 as the ex-spy reported, said the sources, who spoke on condition of anonymity because the investigation is confidential. He wouldn’t have needed a passport for such a trip, because both countries are in the so-called Schengen Area in which 26 nations operate with open borders.

Is it possible to travel to the Czech Republic through Germany without receiving a stamp in one's passport?

Comment: Not sure what the notable claim here is. Look up "Schengen area"?

Comment: "The [Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area) is an area comprising 26 European states that have officially abolished passport and all other types of border control at their mutual borders. The area mostly functions as a single jurisdiction for international travel purposes, with a common visa policy." -- -1 for not doing basic research.

Answer (score 2):

Germany and the Czech Republic are both part of the [Schengen area](http://smartraveller.gov.au/bulletins/Pages/europe_schengen.aspx) - which is comprised of 26 countries that have agreed to a common entry/exit control, and allows unrestricted movement within the area. This area is confused as being contiguous with the EU - but there are in fact [some non-EU countries](https://www.etiasvisa.com/etias-news/etias-countries-difference-eu-schengen-area) in Schengen (eg, Switzerland) and some EU countries outside of Schengen (eg, UK).

So, as long as you were correctly processed and stamped at your entry point (Germany), the Czech Republic do not require an entry stamp as you cross from Germany (you don't even need to present your passport as you travel between Schengen nations).

Comment: though you will not have to present your passport at the border as there is no passport control

Comment: Not at the land border - what about flights? Or are intra-Schengen flights separated from extra-Schengen ones?

Comment: For intra-Schengen flights you do not have to show a passport to immigration officials on departure or on arrival.  The airline will probably want to see ID on boarding though they will not check visa status (commercially they want to make sure you did not transfer your ticket from somebody else).  The police have their usual reserve powers to ask to see ID anywhere, but that is not specific to borders

Comment: @HorusKol Intra-Schengen flights generally leave from the same terminal as domestic flights and, like them, do not involve passport control.

Comment: "are intra-Schengen flights separated from extra-Schengen ones?" Yes, that's exactly it.  See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurt_Airport#Terminal_overview.  The A and Z concourses use an increasingly common approach: internal Schengen passengers are on the lower level while external passengers are upstairs, and for any given flight the boarding area is connected to the appropriate concourse by opening the corresponding doors.